# applescript: establish PPPoE connection

Tags: networking, connection, applescript, pppoe

how would an Applescript look like that connects to a specific PPPoE configuration? i want to trigger this via Launchbar.

(or a more fancy script which checks if the current chosen network location is the right one and if an ethernet cable is plugged in, then connect to the PPPoE service automatically. i'd be completely satisfied with the simpler version though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do shell script "/usr/sbin/scselect [insert appropriate network location]"

tell application "System Events"
    tell network preferences
        connect service "[insert name of PPPoE service]"
    end tell
end tell
```